# Insert a text at a certain position with sed command on an xml file

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a text in an xml file with sed command.
I started to try some basic commands with sed :

```
sed -i -e ' <property name="prop1" ref="ANOTHER_BEAN" /> ' my_config_file.xml
```

it's adding this line but not in the position that I want

The problem for my specific case is that the text should be add to a certain position (certain bean as it's a java config file)

*Example*

```
 <bean id="BEAN_ID_1"
    class="com.toto.BeanClass1"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="prop1" ref="ANOTHER_BEAN_1" />
    <property name="prop2" ref="BEAN1" />
 </bean>

<bean id="BEAN_ID_2"
    class="com.toto.BeanClass2"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="prop_1" ref="ANOTHER_BEAN_2" />
    <property name="prop_2" ref="BEAN2" />
 </bean>
```

I want to add this property to the bean named  'BEAN_ID_1' before the enclosing tag

```
 <property name="property" ref="ANOTHER_BEANXXX" />
```

so the output will be :

```
 <bean id="BEAN_ID_1"
    class="com.toto.BeanClass1"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="prop1" ref="ANOTHER_BEAN_1" />
    <property name="prop2" ref="BEAN1" />
    <property name="property" ref="ANOTHER_BEANXXX" />
 </bean>

<bean id="BEAN_ID_2"
    class="com.toto.BeanClass2"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="prop_1" ref="ANOTHER_BEAN_2" />
    <property name="prop_2" ref="BEAN2" />
 </bean>
```

PS: I can't rely on line number since in production I have no Idea how is the file

Can anybody help me on this ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using an xml parser for xml; would be more robust.

But maybe something like this?

```
sed -i '/<bean id="BEAN_ID_1"/,/<\/bean>/ s/<\/bean>/   <property name="property" ref="ANOTHER_BEANXXX" \/>\n<\/bean>/' my_config_file.xml
```

This means within the range starting with `<bean id="BEAN_ID_1"` and ending with `</bean>`, insert the line    `<property name="property" ref="ANOTHER_BEANXXX" />` right before `</bean>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @frabjous !

Answer (score 2):

Using an XML parser/editor to edit your XML is always a safer approach than trying to fudge it with `sed`.

I've fixed up your XML sample by wrapping it all in `<beans>...</beans>` so that it's valid XML. And here is a solution using `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet edit --subnode '//bean[@id="BEAN_ID_1"]' -t elem -n property --var this '$prev' --insert '$this' -t attr -n name -v property --insert '$this' -t attr -n ref -v 'ANOTHER_BEANXXX' configFile
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans>
  <bean id="BEAN_ID_1" class="com.toto.BeanClass1" scope="prototype">
    <property name="prop1" ref="ANOTHER_BEAN_1"/>
    <property name="prop2" ref="BEAN1"/>
    <property name="property" ref="ANOTHER_BEANXXX"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="BEAN_ID_2" class="com.toto.BeanClass2" scope="prototype">
    <property name="prop_1" ref="ANOTHER_BEAN_2"/>
    <property name="prop_2" ref="BEAN2"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Explanation of the `xmlstarlet` line:

```
# Edit the XML, writing the result to stdout
xmlstarlet edit

# Create a subnode called "property" of "//bean" having an attribute id="BEAN_ID_1"
--subnode '//bean[@id="BEAN_ID_1"]' -t elem -n property

# Identify this new element as "this"
--var this '$prev'

# Insert an attribute called "name" with a value "property" into the new element
--insert '$this' -t attr -n name -v property

# Insert an attributed called "ref" with a value "ANOTHER_BEANXXX" into the new element
--insert '$this' -t attr -n ref -v 'ANOTHER_BEANXXX'

# XML source file
configFile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @roaima !

Comment: Any guidance here please.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974539/how-to-replace-a-variable-in-xml-from-using-shell-script